# search and delete specific search term folder continuously

Tags: file, batch-file

Need help to write a batch file to search c drive and delete all folders and subdirectories that has the word 'text' anywhere in the folder name, which would be running continuously, whenever it finds a folder with that word..
such as if a folder anywhere on the C: is called 'text' or another called '1text2' or 'ninety text documents' it would delete all 3 folders, as they contain the word 'text'

I have got the following, but it only deletes 1 folder and does not detect a folder with the word 'text' anywhere in the folder name:

```
@echo off
for /d /r "c:\" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"=="text" set "folderpath=%%a"
rmdir /s /q "%folderpath%"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `for /d /r "c:\" %%a in (*text*) do rmdir /s /q "%%a"`

Answer (score 1):

```
for /r "c:\" /d %%a in (*text*) do echo rd /s /q "%%a"
```

Recursively (`/r`) for each folder (`/d`) under `c:\` containing `text`, recursively remove the folder.

The `rd` command is echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` to perform the deletion.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /d /r "c:\" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"=="text" set "folderpath=%%a"
rmdir /s /q "%folderpath%"
```

three problems:

1. your `for` searches every "text" and overwrites %folderpath% every time, resulting in setting it to the last founding.
2. you are looking for  `"%%~nxa"=="text"`, but this does not test if "text" is *included*.
3. you use a variable inside a block, you need delayed expansion.

Try this instead (untested):

```
@echo off
for /d /r "c:\" %%a in (*) do ( 
  echo %%~nxa |find /i "text">nul && echo rmdir /s /q "%%a"
)
```

remove the `echo`, if you are satisfied with the output.

Attention, this may lead to unwanted deletions (for example "Textures" does contain "Text")

Comment: Thanks, i didnt realise it will lead to unwanted deletions, thanks for the head up.